# Pandas - Plot the timely distributed usage of two types in one plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe as the following:

```
payment     time of 
            the day

credit card 23
cash        1
cash        2
credit card 5
cash        2
credit card 8
credit card 22
credit card 23
credit card 22
cash        22
```

Expected Output:

x-axis is the time of the day, and y-axis is the payment count based on the time of the day.

```
a stackplot of these two payment types based on different time of the day
```

My idea is:

```
idxes = [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, ... ,  22,  23]

# credit card payment     counts based on the time of a day
arr1  = [ ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?]    

# cash payment counts based on the time of a day
arr2  = [ ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?]    

plt.stackplot(idxes, arr1, arr2, colors= ['r', 'g')
plt.show()
```

How could I get the arr1 and arr2?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `unstack`

```
df_hours = pd.DataFrame(list(range(24)),columns=['time of the day'])

df_unstacked = df.groupby(['time of the day', 'payment'])['payment'].count().unstack()
df_merged = df_hours.merge(df_unstacked, on='time of the day', how='left').set_index("time of the day")

df_merged.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10))
```

Comment: Some individual hours were missing this way, which may or may not be desired. In business presentation scenarios, IMO, it is very likely that the audience generally expects a 24-houred x-axis.

Comment: If there is no data in some hours, they will be missing. I'll change my code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution uses a trick: sum the uniform dummy weight `1`. The idea is in fact a special case of dealing with non-equal sample weight. After counting is completed, just populate the sum of count into the correct indexes of the required arrays.

### Code

```
# 1. accumulate
# dummy equal weight
df["count"] = 1
# groupby (payment, hour) and sum
df_count = df.groupby(["payment", "time of the day"]).sum()

# 2. populate the required array using index and count
arr1 = np.zeros(24, dtype=int)  # 0 to 23 for the ease of filling
arr2 = np.zeros(24, dtype=int)

for idx, count in df_count["count"].iteritems():
    if idx[0] == "cash":
        arr1[idx[1]] = count
    elif idx[0] == "credit card":
        arr2[idx[1]] = count
```

### Result

```
df_count
Out[27]: 
                             count
payment     time of the day       
cash        1                    1
            2                    2
            22                   1
credit card 5                    1
            8                    1
            22                   2
            23                   2

arr1
Out[29]: 
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])

arr2
Out[30]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2])
```

p.s. If you don't want hour `0`, just plot with `arrN[1:]`.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

arr1 and arr2  is data.values.T

```
data = df.groupby("payment").time_of_the_day.value_counts()
data = data.unstack(level=0).fillna(0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.stackplot(data.index, data.values.T)
ax.legend(data.columns)
fig.savefig("stackplot.png")
```

[image]